# 'xx' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this error `studentHelperClass.Form1.cmbBox is inaccessible due to its protection level`

for this part of my code

```
class studentHC : Form1
{
    public studentHC()
    {
        InsertMethod();
    }

    private void InsertMethod()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn; // connection object;
        string connstring = 
                   "server=localhost;user Id=root;" + 
                   "database=collegesystem;Convert Zero Datetime=True ";
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
        conn.Open();
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM person", conn))
        {
            using (var myReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                cmbBox.Items.Add(myReader["personID"]);
            }
        }
    }

    internal static void insertMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

the above code is for a SELECT query to display the contents of a table called person

and this I have in my Form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MySqlConnection conn; // connection object;
    string connstring = 
               "server=localhost;user Id=root;" +
               "database=collegesystem;Convert Zero Datetime=True ";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connection();
        selectStudent();
    }


    private void selectStudent()
    {
        try
        {
            studentHelperClass.studentHC.insertMethod();
        }

        catch (Exception err)
        {
            lblInfo.Text = " Error reading the database.";
            lblInfo.Text += err.Message;
        }
    }
```

How can I solve this error?

I believe that this is the last error before the program will work

EDIT:

this is thee only part of the code I didn't show you..and it has nothing to do with cmbBox :/

```
private void connection()
{
    try
    {
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring); //make the connection object
        conn.Open(); // try and open the connection
        lblInfo.Text = " server version: " + conn.ServerVersion;
        lblInfo.Text += "\n Connection is :" + conn.State.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblInfo.Text = " Error reading the database.";
        lblInfo.Text += err.Message; ;
    }
```

EDIT NUMBER 2:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.cmbBox = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
    this.lblInfo = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // cmbBox
    // 
    this.cmbBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
    this.cmbBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 9);
    this.cmbBox.Name = "cmbBox";
    this.cmbBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
    this.cmbBox.TabIndex = 0;
```

I have to change that to public?

Ok so I used the properties window to change cmbBox to protected and that removed the error, but now my label for statuses on the database has given me this error after I ran the program, any idea why?
`Error reading the database, method or operation is not implemented`

Comment: Show us the declaration of `cmbBox`

Comment: cmbBox is probably `private` and you are trying to access it from a sub class. You need to make it `protected`. Unfortunately, that code is in the rest of the partial class that you didn't show us.

Comment: are you declaring `cmbBox` as `private`?

Comment: `public partial class Form1 : Form`. There is another part of this code. It's probably generated by the IDE, but you can still access it. Look harder.

Comment: Getting closer, but you are still missing the declarations of the member `cmbBox`. It won't be inside of a method, but at the top of your partial class.

Comment: Now that you have solved the protection issue, select a suitable answer and close this thread. For the new problem, create a new thread and you may post here the link for others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720060/error-reading-the-database-method-or-operation-is-not-implemented

Comment: The new error you're getting now is not related to the one this thread is about; create a new question rather than updating this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to open auto generated partial class of Form1 and change cmbBox to protected. This can be done from the designer view also if you are using Visual Studio.  This should solve the problem.

Comment: No. It should not be set to public unless he decides to use it publicly. (He's not)

Comment: True. That leaves the only option "protected".

Comment: Yes. Please remove the suggestion of setting it to `public` from your answer and you will get my +1. Exposing it to public can open it up to all sorts of issues - including multi-threading issues. If it needs to be modified from another class, then a setter should be created that can ensure thread-safety.

Comment: I have solved the issue, please look at my last edit if you can provide me with some help on the new issue. thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720060/error-reading-the-database-method-or-operation-is-not-implemented

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `cmbBox` was declared as `private` (or maybe you didnt declare any protection level, and it defaults to private). If you can, please change it to be `protected` instead.

If you can't change it for some reason, try:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    protected void AddPerson(Person p)
    {
       cmbBox.Items.Add(p);
    }
}
```

and

```
class studentHC : Form1
{
    public studentHC()
    {
        InsertMethod();
    }

    private void InsertMethod()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn; // connection object;
        string connstring = "server=localhost;user Id=root;database=collegesystem;Convert Zero Datetime=True ";
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
        conn.Open();
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM person", conn))
        {
            using (var myReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                AddPerson(myReader["personID"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have solved the issue, please look at my last edit if you can provide me with some help on the new issue. thanks

Comment: I wouldn't even bother trying to change its protection, the second half of your answer is correct IMO

Comment: @user2469932, that's a completely different problem. I'd follow Imran's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

If the ComboBox is created by IDE,most probably the ComboBox will have been declared `Private`.Try setting it to `Protected under category Modifiers` in the `Properties Window`.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the "cmbBox" object in the Form view. You need to set it's "Modifier" level to Public or Protected.

Comment: It should be set to protected, not public.

Comment: I have solved the issue, please look at my last edit if you can provide me with some help on the new issue. thanks