# Error reading the database, method or operation is not implemented

Tags: c#, mysql

So after fixing an error where I was getting `studentHelperClass.Form1.cmbBox is inaccessible due to its protection level` I got this error when I launched my prorgam `Error reading the database, method or operation is not implemented` by my error label.

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection conn; // connection object;
        string connstring = "server=localhost;user Id=root;database=collegesystem;Convert Zero Datetime=True ";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connection();
            selectStudent();
        }


        private void selectStudent()
        {
            try
            {
                studentHelperClass.studentHC.insertMethod();
            }

            catch (Exception err)
            {
                lblInfo.Text = " Error reading the database.";
                lblInfo.Text += err.Message;
            }
        }
```

That is the code for the form, the following is the class with the method

```
class studentHC : Form1
    {
        public studentHC()
        {
            InsertMethod();
        }

        private void InsertMethod()
        {
            MySqlConnection conn; // connection object;
            string connstring = "server=localhost;user Id=root;database=collegesystem;Convert Zero Datetime=True ";
            conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM person", conn))
            {
                using (var myReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    cmbBox.Items.Add(myReader["personID"]);
                }
            }
        }

        internal static void insertMethod()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

OK, so I got rid of

```
internal static void insertMethod()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

and I changed

```
public studentHC()
{
    InsertMethod();
}

private void InsertMethod()
```

to

```
public studentHC()
{
    insertMethod();
}

private void insertMethod()
```

and now it says `studentHelperClass.studentHC.insertMethod()' is inaccessible due to its protection level`

Comment: You're calling static insertMethod which as you can see is not implemented.

Comment: Why do you have both an `insertMethod` and `InsertMethod` method defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your studentHC class with this

```
class studentHC : Form1
    {
        public studentHC()
        {
            InsertMethod();
        }

        public static void InsertMethod()
        {
            MySqlConnection conn; // connection object;
            string connstring = "server=localhost;user Id=root;database=collegesystem;Convert Zero Datetime=True ";
            conn = new MySqlConnection(connstring);
            conn.Open();
            using (var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM person", conn))
            {
                using (var myReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    cmbBox.Items.Add(myReader["personID"]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

and then replace

```
studentHelperClass.studentHC.insertMethod();
```

With

```
studentHelperClass.studentHC.InsertMethod();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `insertMethod` throws this exception. Just look at its code, it is throwing a `NotImplementedException`...

How to fix this, I can't tell you, because I am really not sure about your class structure here...

One possibility would be to simply move the code from `InsertMethod` into `insertMethod`

Comment: If I don't have that there i get `studentHelperClass.studentHC() does not contain a definition for insert method.;`

Comment: @user2469932: Do you even read the error messages? If you do and you don't understand them, I strongly suggest doing some entry level tutorials on C#. This is the most basic of knowledge...

Comment: Your a friendly one aren't ya, look mate, Its nearly 12pm where I am, I have been screwing around with errors like this all day, I fix one, I get 10 more, so I am very truly sorry that you decided to show up here of your own will and now are complaining about it.

Comment: @user2469932: I just knew that you would take this as an offense. Do you know the saying: [Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach him how to fish and you feed him for a lifetime](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day._Teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)? That's exactly your problem here. Without learning the basics, your programming life will always be as frustrating as today, because you are always just asking for a *single fish* here when you really should learn fishing instead.

Comment: Ok, that's fine I understand, I get you, trust me I do, but I dont have time right now to be learning basics, I need at least ONE THING just ONE THING to work, and then im golden, but I cant even get one thing to work so im a little pissy

Comment: @user2469932: That specific problem you are having here most likely will be fixed by [Dhaval's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18720243/572644). However, it very well might introduce others.

Comment: @user2469932 what daniel is 100% right .. whenever you have time please learn some basics about C# and asp .net it iwll help  you a lot

Comment: @user2469932 Don't bite the hand that feeds you, Daniel's advice is extremely helpful if you ever want to be a developer that isn't helplessly frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of Form1 selectStudent is called which calls insertMethod. But this method is not implemented yet. You have to implement it before calling. There is another method with same name but uppercase first letter. I think you put your code in wrong place.

Put all the code in (uppercase)InsertMethod in (lowercase)insertMethod. This should solve the current problem.